# How to run GUI in my script

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I am using CVAP clustering toolbox that is based on GUI. After loading my data, I am using Run Clustering and Run validation commands, respectively. Then, choosing error rate option from tool menu. I need to repeat this process 20-30 times. And,in each time I need to save and open result file, to look at clustering outputs.To avoid this manual process, Is there any way to run GUI in my script? Basically, I just need to "click" Run clustering and Run validation button then choose Error rate from tool menu in my script.

Comment: I'm assuming you can't write a script that duplicates what the GUI does? If so you can call the GUI from a script, manipulate the tool menu values via the object handle, and then call the callbacks associated with the run buttons.

Comment: If you do not mind can you give me some info about how to use object handle? Or can you recommend me some source to learn. So far, I have not used GUI based toolboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to use a GUI from a script. Assuming you know about GUI's this should make sense. If not let me know.

First get a handle of the GUI

```
guihandle = guidata(GUINAME);
```

Then in your script you can press buttons (execute the button callback function) using this type of command:

```
GUINAME('callback_functionname',guihandle.callback_functionname,callback_inputs,guihandle);
```

This will run whatever the callback does. Just make sure that before this you have manipulated whatever inputs the button callback will need. You mentioned you'll need to choose an error rate option. Since I don't know your exact code it's hard to say exactly how to do this. But from a script you can set the tool menu value like this:

```
set(guihandle.tool_menu,'Value',value);
```

Maybe that isn't a helpful example but that's the idea. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.